# Where to find menu of a mesh?

Tags: objects, workflow

I am having problem with Blender: during my work I created a new mesh and suddenly after rotating it I just lost the option menu for the mesh which consists of its size, alignment and so on.

Can anyone please provide information about how can I can get the menu back?

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing normal Blender behavior. Objects are not permanently parametric. You lose the object's parametric status when you do any of the following:

- manually rotate, translate or scale the object (for instance with shortcut keys <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>)
- go into *Edit Mode* for the object
- click on any other object